# Why mysql select varchar type is very slow

Tags: mysql, varchar

400,000 records in the table

## Table formation

```
id(int,pk)
title varchar(255)
body(text)
```

### Query 1

```
select **title** from qa_question order by id desc limit 300000, 15;
```

Running time **15** Second

### Query 2

```
select **body** from qa_question order by id desc limit 300000, 15;
```

Running time **1.8** Second

I want to know why

Comment: *Why what*? Why does the select query run too slow with varchar columns? What does the `explain plan` say?

Comment: @bonCodigo The question is the title. :-/

Comment: How did you test this? Did you do it in this order, did you do it in any order, did you repeat the test, can it have anything to do with query cache (ordering)

Comment: @chengzhiwei Can you run each query for several times a loop (say 10) and share the timings?

Answer (score 2):

Simple, **ORDER BY** is executed first and then only **LIMIT** works. If you order by even **id**  on so many records that means a large amount of data is being moved around  (varchar and text). If you don't order there then your queries are fast because data is not being moved around like that. The more data there is, the more I/O requests to disk will be generated.

To answer the question in comments below.

Difference could be due to the fact that OP might be using MyISAM storage engine and TEXT is not stored in-row for that. VARCHAR is. [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html). That filesystem storage could be the differnce in sorting time for storing in-row and not in-row. Also read [this nice explanation](http://nicj.net/mysql-text-vs-varchar-performance/)

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit)

Comment: Hanky, The question is not about the order by, but about how returning a different datatype makes the query slower. Do you know what causes the difference between the 1st and 2nd query? Both use `order by`, but one takes almost 1/10 of the other. Also the difference between the 3rd and 4rd query is quite significant (and again it's related to the data type being returned)

Comment: Thanks Hanky, I thought that somehow the answer was related to the storage engine (although chengzhiwei didn't mention which engine he's using).

Comment: @chengzhiwei Then the above mentioned fact explains it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets look closer at your query which has `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 300000, 15`.

What MySQL server has to do to execute it? First, it has to fetch every single record according to primary index on `id` in descending order.
Note, that this has to happen 300k times. Once it reaches 300,000 count, only then server can start to output result rows, and it will be only 15 of them.
If you had used not 300k initial offset, but something smaller, this query would have worked much faster.

Why query1 differs from query2 by factor of 10x? This is because columns of `TEXT` in MySQL [are linked to parent table](http://de.planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=23118) (not stored in it) and retrieving them requires additional lookup, but `VARCHAR` is stored in-table. In your case, `TEXT` column wins because you don't really need to pull your `body` column until you hit row 300,000 (server only pulls relatively small reference to `body` `TEXT` column in another invisible table). But in case of `title` column, server has no choice but to pull full `title` column, even if it is in range of 100 bytes, and this is why it is 10x slower.

It is hard to tell exactly. It could be because first query ran slow, but cached all table data in RAM, so second can run much faster. You should repeat all queries at least 3 times before you can make any conclusions.

My suggestion for you is to find out a way to replace `LIMIT 300000, 15` with

```
WHERE id BETWEEN 300000 AND 300014
```

or equivalent if you can. In this case server will be able to make use of primary index and it will be lightning fast.

Comment: @chengzhiwei yes, timings from a single run are misleading. Average of timings from running it for several times consecutively(in a loop) might give a better reading.

Comment: Which SQL statements are the same effect regardless of the first execution

Comment: I edited my answer to explain this. But, please consider using `BETWEEN` - it will bring your query to millisecond times no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

It is because **varchar** allocates memory before the query is executed i.e. it uses static memory allocation. So, even if the title is shorter than 255 characters, it will reserve the memory for 255 characters.

While you can use **VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8**, alias of nvarchar, which is dynamic and uses the amount of memory according to the length of the title, in this case.

Since you have 400,000 records which is quite a lot, this causes greater running time while using varchar. So, my suggestion is to use **VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8** and avoid using varchar.

Comment: 1.Why text type so fast,
2.My mysql inside no NVARCHAR this type

Comment: You can use `NVARCHAR` in MySQL, but it's only an alias for `VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8`.