# PHP/MySQL using ORDER BY with a LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I created a pagination by roughly following this link:

http://www.awcore.com/dev/1/3/Create-Awesome-PHPMYSQL-Pagination_en#toggle

quite cool. Although I have an issue with my query.

It works fine like this:

```
require 'includes/function.php';

    $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 8;
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

    $statement = "cars WHERE deleted = 'no'";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit} ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

However when I try to add an ORDER BY to this, like so:

require 'includes/function.php';

```
    $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
    $limit = 8;
    $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

    $statement = "cars WHERE deleted = 'no'";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit} ORDER BY model DESC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

or just change the statement like this:

```
$statement = "rcr_cars WHERE deleted = 'no' ORDER BY model DESC";
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in filepath/myfile.php on line 79.
```

Line 79 is this line:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

Can anyone tell me how I am not using the ORDER BY correctly, its got me puzzled. :/

Comment: You are not using it correctly, `ORDER BY` must come before `LIMIT` statement. Switch them and it should work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the query as below

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY model DESC LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit} ");
```

Where you have gone wrong is LIMIT should come after ORDER BY. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Change the query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY model DESC LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit}") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY model DESC LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit} ");
```