# JPQL : select a set of n lowest / highest values

Tags: select, set, max, jpql, min

I've searched a lot, asked my DBA/Java developer friends, but did not find a satisfactory answer.
Here is my table `(Showing only 3 columns)`
TBL_ Jobs

```
Job_ID(auto increment PK|Job_posting_date| city|Already_applied_flag
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                       |  1/1/2001   | Tezpur |

2                       |  1/1/2010   | Jakarta|   X(already applied) 
3                       |   1/1/2003  | Paris|

----Thousands of rows...
```

Every day, my java program picks 50 jobs from the Jobs table, applies to them and then , marks them as **already applied** so that it will not apply to the same jobs again.

The problem is, the table is not ordered according to the job_posting_date, but my program has to pick the **LATEST** jobs first. (of course, as we keep running it, it will start applying to OLD jobs )

So my question is:
   How do I select 50 LATEST jobs every day?
The solutions I am thinking of

```
1) SELECT a row for MAX( Job_posting_date )
      apply to the job. Mark it as applied
            Repeat 50 times
          ----Extremely inefficient
2) Select ALL the Rows:
        Order by  (Job_posting_date)
            Pick the top 50
3) Somehow reorder the database table ? ( JOB_ID is a foreign key in other tables, so changing it won't be easy)
```

This seems like a common problem to have. What am I missing here ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general rows in relational database tables do not have order (database specifics to aside). Ordering result is done in JPQL and limiting number of results via [Query.setMaxResults](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29). For example:

```
String jpql = "SELECT j FROM Jobs ORDER BY jobPostingDate";
Query q = em.createQuery(jpql);
q.setMaxResults(50);
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found this post, where it says: orderby happens first, and then, limit is  imposed. Hence it will serve my purpose.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit