# How to order a MySQL query by a specific column?

Tags: mysql, sorting

i have a query here, and I am trying to sort the order they output by the column "rank", what would i add to my query exactly to do this? here is my code:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                        FROM leaderboards 
                        WHERE game_id=2 AND mode_id=1 and map_id=15 
                        LIMIT 0, 100');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - ORDER BY & LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order by a specific column, use the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                        FROM leaderboards 
                        WHERE game_id=2 AND mode_id=1 and map_id=15 
                        ORDER BY rank
                        LIMIT 0, 100');
```

Answer (score 1):

you even can use more that one field to sort, See below

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                        FROM leaderboards 
                        WHERE game_id=2 AND mode_id=1 and map_id=15 
                        ORDER BY rank, rank2
                        LIMIT 0, 100');
```