# Getting minimum of top n rows

Tags: mysql, limit, rows, minimum

I wish to get min(somecolumn) from table from first n rows in MySQL. What is the best query to get the result?

So far I found

```
select min(a.column) from (select column from table limit 2000) a

select min(a.column) from table a INNER JOIN  (select column from table b limit 2000) on a.pricolumn = b.pricolumn.
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

`select min(t.columnName) from tableName as t limit 10` (Here n limit is for first 10 rows as example)

OR

`select outerTable.columnName from (select distinct t.columnName from tableName as t order by t.columnName asc limit 10) as outerTable limit 1,1`

Comment: Hi Prakit thanks for your reply    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit as per above post   Query "select min(t.columnName) from tableName as t limit 10 " will return min(t.columname)  from whole table not among 10 records but your second query will work. but my concern is second query not using index so it executes very slow

Answer (score 0):

Try the below syntax:

`SELECT min(columname) FROM tablename limit n`

Comment: Hi Ritobroto, thanks for your reply 

Query "select min(t.columnName) from tableName as t limit 10 " will return min(t.columname) from whole table not among 10 records.

Comment: please try: `SELECT min(columname) FROM tablename WHERE columnname BETWEEN lowerlimit AND higherlimit LIMIT n;`

Do you want this?