# Lost some records after query with dual sorting and limit

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

At the mysql query of a large table (1 million records) with dual sorting and limit, there are lost some records. For example:

```
SELECT rec.id, rec.Price, rec.RegionName, rec.isPayed, rec.isTop 
FROM Records rec
LEFT JOIN Region reg ON reg.RegionID = rec.RegionID 
WHERE rec.Type = "Apartment" AND rec.Transaction = "Sale" AND rec.IsPublished = 1 
ORDER BY rec.isTop DESC, rec.Price ASC 
LIMIT 160, 20
```

I see the solution only through the union ... but maybe you know better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your current output and how are the "lost records" causing you to see something other than what you expect?

Comment: For example https://habrastorage.org/files/db8/49c/c88/db849cc888d64655ad6a314137aa540f.png And afrer sorting i cant find row with id=6 on any of the pages

Comment: Are you sure that `id=6` records should be appearing?  Maybe the `WHERE` clause is filtering these out on the conditions you have.

Comment: Yes, i'm shure. When I remove one of sorting - result is correct.

Comment: I think it's because of the peculiarities of mysql. First applied the limit and then make sorting. When isTop records more than 20 he loses some ...

Comment: MySQL orders first then limits, q.v. [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit).

Comment: Yes then I make one order by. 
But now i'm not shure with two...

Comment: The number of orders should not make a difference.  Check your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The fact is that WHERE is correct and removing only one of the sorts I see recording id=6 on one of pages. Frankly speaking, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: How about trying this: Add `id =6` to your `WHERE` clause and see what you get back.  Maybe the sorting is also chopping off the records with `id=6`.