# how to orderby after applying limit in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the information from DB in such a way, the limit should be 3 rows and out of which i want to sort by descending order.
I used

```
select * from table where coloumn = 'Myfilter' order by serialNumber desc limit 3
```

after  the execution I am not getting the latest three records rather the first three records ordered by descending.

Comment: your column **serialNumber** type ????

Comment: *after the execution I am not getting the latest three records ...* based on which field? SQL tables are unordered sets of data. You always need a field to define row order. Which is this field in your case?

Comment: he probably wants to take the first 3 records firsrt and reorder it to which who is latest among the 3

Comment: @KelvinBarsana What does *first* mean? MySQL doesn't keep track of records in any predefined order. You *always* need a reference field to define row order.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos maybe an additional condition should be applied before limiting the result to 3 and reordering the result

Comment: Can you show the sample data output?

Comment: this will helpful for your reason
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query solves my question thank you all for suggestions,

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE coloumn='myFilter' ORDER BY serialnumber desc LIMIT 3) a ORDER BY serialnumber asc
```

the query uses to select the latest 3 rows ordered by big to small serial number then again the selected rows order where reversed, thnx @Kelvin Barsana

Answer (score 2):

Applying limit before order by

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE coloumn = 'Myfilter' ORDER BY serialNumber LIMIT 3) a ORDER BY serialNumber DESC
```

Comment: @Strawberry he didn't indicate that there should be an order by before limiting the results, so that's the only query i can create.. order by in the subquery can be added if he'll require

Comment: Regardless, we know that there should be one. Rows in an RDBMS represent unordered sets so wherever there is LIMIT there must also be ORDER BY. But if you don't want my vote, that's fine too ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry okay got your point and since that i want your vote, thanks

Comment: thnx for the reply, `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE coloumn='myFilter' ORDER BY serialnumber desc LIMIT 3) a ORDER BY serialnumber asc`  solves my problem

Comment: Could you please tell, what does the `a` means?

Comment: @Sobhani, it is an alias for the subquery if I'm not mistaken which I believe is required. This answer is quite old that is why I am not so sure.

Comment: Thanks, it's old, so is there any replacement for the `a` now? or is it still relevant?

Comment: @Sobhani I think it is still relevant as long as it works.. syntax does not update much as for how mysql rolls

Comment: as for literal replacement for 'a', I think it could be any character

Answer (score -3):

"SELECT * FROM table WHERE coloumn = 'Myfilter' ORDER BY serialNumber DESC LIMIT 3";