# Mysql help needed sorting columns

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Would you help me out as I am new to sql. I am using the following mySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE TagNo LIKE '%' ORDER BY TagNo DESC, id DESC;
```

My `id` is auto-incremented every time a new `TagNo` is added.

I get this:

```
TagNo, id: 

 - 9, 4 
 - 9, 3  
 - 9, 2  
 - 9, 1  
 - 8, 400  
 - 8, 399  
 - 8, 398  
 - 8, 397
```

But I need the latest 3 id for any given TagNo.

```
TagNo, id: 

- 9, 4 
- 9, 3  
- 9, 2  

- 8, 400  
- 8, 399  
- 8, 398
```

I tried this from Bill Karwin post but GROUP By only shows 1 tag and having COUNT(*) seems to restrict only id with value < 3 .. id dynamically grows per TagNo

SELECT i1.*
FROM database i1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ct_database i2
  ON (i1.TagNo = i2.TagNo AND i1.id < i2.id)
GROUP BY i1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
ORDER BY TagNo

I've been trying for a week to figure out.It would be great if someone can help.

Comment: I would suggest you using LIMIT function. And check out the link it might be helpful.MYSQL - ORDER BY & LIMIT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit

Comment: It seems like you would possibly need more than 1 tag number at a time.  If this is correct, Limit would not necessarily work; and it seems the ID's could grow at disproportionate rates.   So for each tag you need to get the ID equal to or greater than the 3rd newest ID for each tag.  is that correct?

Comment: @xQbert Yes you are correct. I did SELECT * FROM tags WHERE TagNo LIKE '%' ORDER BY TagNo DESC, id DESC LIMIT 3;  It only gives me the 1st 3 from a single Tag and all other Tags are ignored.   How can I solve this?

Comment: @BillKarwin Updated my question. Hope to seek you expert advise